# Embedded Login Error

Tags: community, login, login-errors, embedded

We're are trying to implement an embedded login page on an external website where our Partner users can log in to using their Partner Community credentials. We followed the documentation on how to do this and tried to just add it to a basic "Hello World" page but are getting this error when loading the page in a browser:

`Enter the trusted domains, for example, localhost, @.somedomain.com.`

Anyone have any ideas? Is this a error in setting up on the Salesforce side or something on our domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was fixed by including this in the < head > section

```
<meta name="salesforce-allowed-domains" content="embeddedlogin.heroku.com">
```